# How to handle bounce mail sent to the VERP address

Tags: postfix

We have our postfix configured to handle mail for our websites. For every website we have configured a bounce handling user with

```
local_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_maps
```

The file recipient_maps looks like:

```
site1_bounce@our-domain.com          site1_bounce/
site2_bounce@our-domain.com          site2_bounce/
...
```

We're using lmtp for postfix to communicate with dovecot with local delivery:

```
local_transport = lmtp:unix:private/lmtp-dovecot
```

When one of our websites sends mail it uses the postfix VERP feature by using the senmail command options

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -XV -t -i
```

All of this works nicely, and we're getting bounces in different IMAP folders.

By checking the reputation of our mail server I stumbled over one RBL that black lists our mail server, http://v4bl.org. If I understand the informations correctly the reason for this is because we fail 1 test that can be checked out here

http://multirbl.valli.org/fcrdns-test/

If I choose "test by sending an email" I'm getting 1 error, namely, the test program tries to send an email to our envelope RCPT TO address, that is e.g.

```
site1_bounce+testuser=testdomain.tld@our-domain.com
```

which obviously fails because we don't have a local mail account for every generated VERP address.

One real world case would be that a recipient mail server accepts a mail from our postfix and sends a bounce mail later to the RCPT TO address.

So how do we map those VERP addresses back to our bounce handling mail accounts? We tried our luck with

```
alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/verp_alias_maps
```

with verp_alias_maps being:

```
/^site1_bounce\+.+@our-domain.com/       site1_bounce
/^site2_bounce\+.+@our-domain.com/       site2_bounce
...
```

but it appears as postfix ignores our ailas_maps file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use postfix config parameter "recipient_delimiter". Set it to "+".

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

---

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5404399
- Allowing emails with a plus (+) symbol to land in the same Zimbra mailbox

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux! [Please don't just post a link as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259), both because the linked site may be unavailable, and because as it is your answer doesn't show what it's about. Summarize the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Matthias If that answer solved your problem, please [mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask). However, for the sake of future visitors, it would be better if the accepted answer contained the solution, rather than merely a link to a link to the solution.